# Hadoop in Cloudera path VMware

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Hi I have implemented my average word count in java in cloudera vm 4.2.1 p and I have converted to Jar file and ran the command: hadoop jar averagewordlength.jar stubs.AvgWordLength shakespeare wordleng

Next: I have run the Shakespeare correctly and unable to run my file (Which I have created: newfile). It is throwing an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
>   path does not exist: hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020/user/training/newfile    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1064)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1081)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:993)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:946)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java)

please guide in which path to paste the newfile for checking my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your Hadoop configuration is incorrect.

`hdfs://0.0.0.0` is not a valid address

cloudera vm 4.2.1 ? Try to download the newer CDH 5.x VM

Answer (score 0):

I got it by command

hadoop fs -put localpath